# Error in gam function in R

Tags: r, mgcv

I have a problem with my R code about a multiple linear regression. 
First, I try to use the gam function but this gives me an error. 
Here is the code:

```
install.packages("nlme")
library("mgcv")
library("ggplot2")
#Import dataset
setwd("/Users/Sarah/Documents/Master T&O/Master 1/Statistics IV/Assignment 2 ")
weight_data = read.csv("WeightLossGroup190.csv", sep = "", dec = ".", header = TRUE)

#Name of used data
weight <- weight_data$weight  
date <- weight_data$date 
dayNr <- weight_data$dayNumber 
time <- weight_data$time 
#Check linearity 
gam1 <- gam(as.numeric(weight_data$weight) ~ s(as.numeric(weight_data$dayNumber)) + s(as.numeric(weight_data$time)))
summary(gam1)
plot.gam(gam1, se = FALSE, rug = TRUE, all.terms = TRUE)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I googled the error message you posted, and I think [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-October/143569.html) will help you along.

Comment: Your data doesn't have sufficient observations to support as many degrees of freedom as you are asking for. You need to set a smaller value of `k` than the default in at least one of the smoothers. Also, never use `$` in formulas. `gam` has a `data` argument for a reason. Make sure that you variables are numeric before you pass them to `gam`.

Comment: I tried this : gam1 <- gam(weight ~ s(dayNr2) + s(time2),k=2, data= weight_data)
But then I get this error: Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: `k` is an argument of `s` and not of `gam`.

Comment: Still get this error: Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
In addition: Warning message:
In smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
  basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible

Comment: You might need to show your data and updated code. The error means exactly what I've explained in my first comment.

Comment: here is the link to the data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lVMhJyT9s44h-KAPCL3km9GHcEFwdPB0

Comment: This is the updated code: dayNr2 <- as.numeric(weight_data$dayNumber)
time2 <- as.numeric(weight_data$time)
gam1 <- gam(weight ~ s(dayNr2) + s(time2, k=2), data= weight_data)
summary(gam1)
plot.gam(gam1, se = FALSE, rug = TRUE, all.terms = TRUE)

Comment: I won't visit a google drive. But I noticed that you set `k` only in one of the two smoothers. Also, you should make sure that the variables are numeric within the data.frame. Your code creates separate variables outside of it and you don't use these within `gam`. If you have non-numeric variables but expected them to be numeric, you need to fix your data import, usually by specifying `na.strings`.

Comment: Thank you, but can you maybe explain what k is? Because I think I don't get the idea of k correctly..

Comment: See `help("s")` and `help("choose.k")` but you may have to study a textbook about GAMs. `k` basically sets the maximum degrees of freedom the penalized smoother can have.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try controlling the number of knots with "k = " in the gam.